# join and then select list into list with linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have three models like bellow:

> Document {   Guid Id,   int Code   List Items, }
>
> Item {   Guid Id,Guid DocumentId,   string Name,   List ExitHistories }
>
> ExitHistory {   Guid Id, Guid ItemId,  DateTime ExitDateTime }

I want to select a document with some id and join the three tables and select the result. I write something like this but I cannot complete it that I can have ExitHistories in Items. Can anyone help me?

```
var document1 = (
        from documents in context.Documents
        where documents.Id == request.Id
        join items in context.Items on documents.Id equals items.DocumentId into i
        select new 
        {
            Id = documents.Id,
            Code = documents.Code,
            Items = i
        }
    ).First();
```

I try to have my exitHistories in my items when I select document but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you add model classes with their navigation properties?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a `context.ExitHistories` I believe the query below is what you're looking for. You need to do what MS [in their documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause#example) call a "GroupInnerJoin". I.e. join your group of `items` with the `context.ExitHistories`:

```cs
var foundDocument = (
    from document in context.Documents
    where document.Id == request.Id
    join item in context.Items on document.Id equals item.DocumentId into items
    select new 
    {
        Id = document.Id,
        Code = document.Code,
        Items = from item2 in items
                join exitHistory in context.ExitHistories on item2.Id equals exitHistory.ItemId into exitHistories
                select new
                {
                    Id = item2.Id,
                    Name = item2.Name,
                    ExitHistories = exitHistories
                }
    }
).First();
```

A simple demonstration: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sARzOf

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have to select exitHistories for each item in items list. for each item I have to have a list of exitHisories.

Comment: @MiladAbdi I see, thanks for the elaboration. I've updated the answer to hopefully do that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer it's great and I use it. but I just have a little problem with it. I can use it when I have a list of documents but I cannot use when I use it with database context and say cannot conver to query.

Comment: @MiladAbdi You should describe in your question which tools you're using then. If you're using EF, then I suggest taking a look at [how to load data from related entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/).